# Infinity cascade IO expand module

Tags: c++, wiringpi

Has anybody used Infinity cascade IO expand module for Raspberry PI?
Like the one described here http://www.bananapi.com/index.php/purchase/2-uncategorised/36-banana-pi-io-extend-board, but only red.

I'm trying to understand the source code, because everything I try to connect is not working.

What Q port should I use for connecting leds?
Thank you.

Comment: Is this designed to be operated with the raspberry Pi?

Comment: Yeah. I found the same code for a red module that was targeted for RPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the component linked above use a serial approach. 3 pins are used to command it. **SER** is used for serial data transmission, **SRCLK** to push bits down the way and **RCLK** to expose stored values on wires.